# Move subfigure captions in subfigure package

Tags: captions, subfloats

I am writing a manuscript for a journal which have specified to use the `subfigure` package, instead of `subfig` or `subcaption`. I am aware that `subfigure` is deprecated but I cannot change the journal styling.

I am simply trying to shift a caption horizontally to the left. I am doing this to  compensate for the difference in image sizes between the subfigures, which shifts the caption more to the right.

Is this possible within the `subfigure` package?

Below is example code

```latex
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \subfigure[Label 1]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{img1.png}
    }
    \hfill
    \subfigure[Label 2]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.279\textwidth]{img2.png}
    }
    \hfill
    \subfigure[Label3]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.342\textwidth]{img3.png}
    }
    \caption{
        Here's my main caption
    }
    \label{fig:one}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: If journal provide template for their publication, don't change anything. It is up to them, how should caption to be.

Comment: Welcome! First: see Zarko's comment. Second: if you want to change the captions nevertheless, provide a complete small document (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`) showing the problem, with a precise description (maybe even an image) explaining what should be shifted where. Note that you can use the predefined images `example-image.png`, `example-image-a.png` etc instead of your private ones. Maybe your problem stems from wrong bounding boxes of your images. But we cannot tell if you don't provide sufficient information.